# JQuery cookies + animation, DIVS, and wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, cookies

I've got the following [setup](http://blog.spundge.com) which is working well, **except for the cookies part**. The JQuery is controlled by the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#headershadow").hide();
    $("#greenbanner").show();
    $("#bigx").click(function () {
        $("#greenbanner").hide(1000);
        $("#headershadow").show(500);
        $.cookie('greencookie', 'true', {
            expires: 1,
            path: '/'
        });
    });
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/HeaderShadow.png" id="headershadow" />
    <div id="greenbanner">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/Devices.png" id="devices">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/bigx.png" id="bigx">
        <div id="bannertext">Spundge lets you discover, <br />curate, and create better content. <br /><br /><div id="jointhedarkside"><a style="color:#ffffff;" href="https://www.spundge.com/account/signup/">Get Started - It's Free</a></div>   </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using the [following cookies JQuery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) from GitHub, and I seem to be able to set the cookies properly, but I have no idea how to setup the code so that the web page recognizes the cookie and doesn't load the `#greenbanner` `div`. All the if/else combinations I've tried have been useless.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell me if it work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#headershadow").hide();
    if (!$.cookie('greencookie')){
        $("#greenbanner").show();
    }
    $("#bigx").click(function () {
        $("#greenbanner").hide(1000);
        $("#headershadow").show(500);
        $.cookie('greencookie', 'true', {
            expires: 1,
            path: '/'
        });
    });
});
```

If its ok I will add a brief explanation about what I did.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I copied in your code to the site (blog.spundge.com) but unfortunately it doesn't work, the div still reloads everytime I open a new page, even after the cookie is set. :c I can't think why nothing is working.

Comment: So add a CSS rule `display:none;` on line 1959 of your CSS file. for div `#greencookie` then it will only appear if the cookie is not present